# How to get a notification like the mail app on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, banner, foreground

My understanding is that both local and remote notification in iOS will not be displayed if the application is in the foreground.

However if I open the mail app on my iPhone and check my email, then on some occasions i get a banner shown to tell me I have received emails. This occurs when the email app is in the foreground.

Does anyone know how this is done (preferably on Swift)? Or is this privilege only available for Apple written applications.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` method in your `AppDelegate`.

If you want to handle them by inflating views or whathaveyou, you need to do it in that particular method.

Comment: Inside that method you can check the application's state to determine if it's in the foreground or background.

Comment: I know how to handle the notification, but what I need to know is what Apple are using in that case to show the notification? Because all their documentation states that local or remote notification will not be displayed if your app is in the foreground

Comment: i do not think what you see are notifications, mail app should be inflating them as custom views in its appDelegate. for example, look at Whatsapp, it notifies you but with a custom view.